# SQL query to get sum of each element in seperate columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I had asked this question few days back but the solution did not work perfectly and hence I am asking this question with the new logic-

```
  SELECT   person_number,taxable_earn, Basic_Life,Tax_Units
      FROM   (SELECT     ppa.effective_date, 
                         pra.result_value , 
                         pra.elementname, 
                         prd.person_number 
                FROM     pay_pay_relationships_dn prd 
               INNER JOIN pay_payroll_rel_actions pra ON prd.payroll_relationship_id = pra.payroll_relationship_id 
               INNER JOIN pay_payroll_actions ppa ON pra.payroll_action_id = ppa.payroll_action_id 
               INNER JOIN pay_all_payrolls_f pap ON ppa.element_type_id = pap.element_type_id 
               WHERE ppa.payroll_id = pap.payroll_id
                 AND ppa.effective_date BETWEEN :p_start_date AND :p_end_date)
     PIVOT    (SUM(result_value )
               FOR elementname IN ('taxable_earn' taxable_earn, 'Basic_Life' Basic_Life, 'Tax_Units' Tax_Units))
```

The above query is giving me an output like -

```
   EMPLOYEENUMBER           taxable_earn  Basic_Life     Tax_Units
           10                         6.7                           
           10                                       7.8             
           10                                                       9.2
```

I want the output to look like -

```
     EMPLOYEENUMBER         taxable_earn  Basic_Life     Tax_Units
       10                       6.7         7.8             9.2
```

How can i tweak the above query to get this output ?

Comment: How does your query give you the column name `EMPLOYEENUMBER` in the output, when in the query you select `person_number`? Is it so hard to copy and paste, both the query and the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `ppa.effective_date,`  from your nested subquery :

```sql
SELECT   person_number,taxable_earn, Basic_Life,Tax_Units
      FROM   (SELECT     
                         pra.result_value , 
                         pra.elementname, 
                         prd.person_number 
                FROM     pay_pay_relationships_dn prd 
               INNER JOIN pay_payroll_rel_actions pra ON prd.payroll_relationship_id = pra.payroll_relationship_id 
               INNER JOIN pay_payroll_actions ppa ON pra.payroll_action_id = ppa.payroll_action_id 
               INNER JOIN pay_all_payrolls_f pap ON ppa.element_type_id = pap.element_type_id 
               WHERE ppa.payroll_id = pap.payroll_id
                 AND ppa.effective_date BETWEEN :p_start_date AND :p_end_date)
     PIVOT    (SUM(result_value )
               FOR elementname IN ('taxable_earn' taxable_earn, 'Basic_Life' Basic_Life, 'Tax_Units' Tax_Units))
```

Comment: Obviously the correct answer. (Also, almost obvious to me, this will **not** be selected as the correct answer - just based on past experience.)

Answer (score 2):

Use the max function on each column of the outer most select and group by afterward, leaving your current sub-select as is:

```
select person
     , max(taxable_earn) taxable_earn
     , max(basic_life)   basic_life
     , max(tax_units)    tax_units 
  from ( <your current sub select as is > )
 group by person;
```

Comment: Seriously? Leave the subquery as is, with the PIVOT operation (an aggregate), and then aggregate by person again? WHY? See Sayan Malakshinov's answer for the correct way to fix the OP's query. -1 from me since this answer gives truly bad advice.

Comment: @mathguy I made no attempt to evaluate the original query, just took the results given and demonstrated how get results requested. There seemed no indication hat the result was wrong, just undesired format.  Perhaps I misunderstood OPs statement "asking this question with the new logic". Oh well it is what it is.

Comment: My point is that, when the poster makes the effort to post his or her query, a good answer WILL make an attempt to evaluate the original query - if your goal is to help the poster.

Answer (score 1):

When there are common values and you want to gather them at one place, try using "*Group by*" clause

Comment: No generalities, please. If you have an answer specific to the question asked in this thread, please share it with us. (Hint: "group by" is not needed.)